More flash memory with SD card
I am pretty sure that everyone have seen the low flash memory error, the same I have got while making my raycaster. So, I was thinking that is there any way to increase the flash memory of ESP32 with an SD card?
I'll connect an SD card module to ESP32 and I'll have 4GB of flash memory. Is there any way? The SD card should act as an external flash memory in any way.

Have you try to change the partition scheme setting (from IDE, tools->partition scheme)? If you don't use OTA, you could allocate more flash memory to your code. SD card is more for storing data, it does not help if you are running of program space.

I did but my code exceeded even that limit and there is much to add to my 3d game

Is there any way to use a sd card as my flash memory

There are ESP32 boards with 8MB or even 16MB available in the market. Or replace your existing flash chip with bigger one if you are capable of doing electronics hack (provided the module use external flash chip). Another alternative is to pick a linux box (such as Raspberry Pi) with CPU instead of a MCU for game development.

I know I can do it but if sd card could act as an storage for flash then it could help in other project . But right now I am determined to do this

Can I exchange og flash chip with the sd card

I mean sd card module ,externally without opening the steel case

You need to understand how MCU work. For MCU, program is directly executed in flash memory, only variables get load into RAM, it is therefore does not load program from storage such as SD card. For CPU (like your PC or Raspberry Pi), program is loaded from storage (hard disk, usb, sd card, whatever) and execute in RAM.

Actually I found a code to do the same thing.should I send it??

You should be able to use the Huge APP partition scheme:

Reference: [Solved] Increasing the flash memory size Using Partition in ESP32....
